# Wrong total count displayed for 'offensive flags' filter on flagging history section of flag-summary page

Tags: bug, flag-history

On my flag summary page
https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/814548?group=0&status=0&page=2

I can see one helpful `rude or offensive` flag for question [jQuery ajax .load() results in 500 error in Internet Explorer only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006835/jquery-ajax-load-results-in-500-error-in-internet-explorer-only/33686755#33686755). But there is no `helpful` category displayed under `offensive flags`. The total count should be 2 with 1 helpful flag.

Answer (score 3):

The flag summary page provides a breakdown based on flag type:

- Post Flags - this includes NAA, VLQ, other flags
- Comment Flags - all comment flag types - too chatty, not constructive, obsolete, *rude or offensive*, etc
- Spam Flags
- Offensive Flags

Your flag history is showing 1 Offensive Flag which was declined. This is the only Offensive Flag that you have in your history.

The *rude or offensive* item you see in your history is for a comment [that you flagged on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006835/jquery-ajax-load-results-in-500-error-in-internet-explorer-only/33686755#33686755). This item is counted in the comment flags not in the offensive flags because they are different flag types.

This isn't a bug. The flag history is displayed by flag type and comment flags are different from offensive flags.